# Leapfrog scheme but with initial position update

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) we learn that if we have a system
$$
\begin{align}
    \dot x &= v \\
    \dot v &= a(x)
\end{align}
$$
then a possible Leapfrog scheme could be
$$
\begin{align}
    v_{t + \delta/2} &= v_t + \frac{\delta}{2}a(x_t) && \text{(half velocity step)} \\
    x_{t + \delta} &= x_t + \delta v_{t + \delta/2} && \text{(full position step)} \\
    v_{t + \delta} &= v_{t + \delta/2} + \frac{\delta}{2} a(x_{t+\delta}) && \text{(half velocity step)}
\end{align}
$$

> Can I instead do Leapfrog but doing half position steps and full velocity steps?
> $$
> \begin{align}
>     x_{t+\delta/2} &= x_t + \frac{\delta}{2} v_t && \text{(half position step)} \\
>     v_{t+\delta} &= v_t + \delta a(x_{t+\delta/2}) && \text{(full velocity step)} \\
>     x_{t + \delta} &= x_{t+\delta/2} + \frac{\delta}{2} v_{t+\delta} && \text{(half position step)}
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: Sure. Why would you want to? Or why would you prefer one over the other? Do you feel like the DEs are "more stiff" in $x$ than in $v?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister The notes I am reading basically do that but don’t motivate it at all, nor give a proof of correctness. All the Leapfrog descriptions I have found start with the velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, the Leapfrog Verlet scheme is the simple iteration
\begin{align}
    v_{t + \delta/2} &= v_{t - \delta/2} + \delta ·a(x_t)  \\
    x_{t + \delta} &= x_t + \delta· v_{t + \delta/2}
\end{align}
where the velocity is always only taken at the half-steps. For energy computations or similar where the full state is needed at the time points, the velocity is interpolated as $v_t=\frac12(v_{t + \delta/2}+v_{t - \delta/2})$. Inserting the velocity update formula results in the velocity half-step formulas. If that is done systematically, the resulting equation block is one variant of what is called Velocity Verlet.

The other variant, shifting everything by a half-step and using the mean of the position for $x_t$, is less used as the position sequence deviates from that obtained by the original Verlet (Newton-Stormer-...) scheme
$$
x_{t + \delta}=2x_t-x_{t - \delta}+\delta^2·a(x_t)
$$